# matlab - find start and stop of an interesting signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a signal that looks like this : 
[image]

I would like to find a way to locate the start and end of the portion of the middle.

What I did, is for the values above and below 0.5 to be a constant ==> 1, and if I find many times 1 in the row it means that it's my signal... but it's not a good way I guess! First my "threshold" would not be every time 0.5, and I am sure it exists some better way to do so.

If you guys have some documentations or ideas about that..

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you provide an example signal file? and what are the characteristics that all your signals have in common?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lm5pm9232yphwwb/acceleration.txt?dl=0 here is a .txt file with the signal (Fe = 101Hz). The signal is the acceleration of someone running. The characteristic in common is that there is a repetition of a sinusoids if you filter the signal with low-pass filter at 5Hz. @Finn Thank you

Comment: You will probably get a better answer to this on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ since this question seems to be more related to DSP than to actual programming. There should be persons with Matlab knowledge there as well and that the post uses code written in Matlab (and seems to request some example code in the answer) does not mean that it cannot be a DSP question.

Comment: If you just want to adjust your threshold to the right level, simply calculate the Maximum and minimum of your signal and set the threshold to be 50% or 75% depending on your signal, but this is never going to be truly robust, if you want a robust method, please go and do some research and come back.

Comment: A guess is that you can look at the signal's autocorrelation and see when you get a good correlation of your signal. I assume that the first data is mostly noise so this should be random and have a fairly low correlation. I will leave it at this point so you will have to do the research by yourself I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you all. Those info give me some directions to make my research. I had no idea how to begin :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the others it is more of a DSP question and  dsp.stackexchange.com will propably give you a better answer, but until then this might help:

```
data=csvread('acceleration.txt',1)

threshold_y=max(data)*0.5; %Thanks to GameOfThrows
thershold_x=101; %how many zeros can be between to ones to still count as continuous 
addframe=50; %if you want a little bit of data before and after the active area
logic_index=data>threshold_y; 
num_index=find(logic_index);
distance=diff(num_index);

gaps=[1 ; find(distance>thershold_x)]; %find the gaps bigger than your threshold 
final_index=false(length(data),1); 

for i=1:length(gaps)-1 %add ones between 
    final_index(num_index(gaps(i)+1)-addframe:num_index(gaps(i+1))+addframe)=true;
end
plot(x,data,x,final_index);
```

it is basically what you decribed in your question but with the addition of dealing with the zeros inbetween an area. thanks to @GameofThrows for the threshold idea.

Comment: Great! Thank you, it works perfectly :) It's a really good way ! @Finn